# View resulting systemd config

Tags: configuration, systemd

Is is possible to view the resulting config of some unit or `journald.service`?

They are assembled from multiple files and I am never sure if the option is applied.

For example I've added a file `/usr/lib/systemd/hello.conf.d/hello.conf`:

```
[Journal]
Storage=permanent
```

to store logs permanently.

The documentation promised to create a directory `/var/log/journal/`, but nothing happened.

Comment: Plz check `/run/systemd/journal`

Comment: It is always there as before. How it is related to the permanent storage?

Comment: If you or some program delete `/var/log/journal/`, systemd will not recreate it automatically and instead will write its logs to /run/systemd/journal in a nonpersistent way.

Comment: It will recreate it automatically if `Storage=permanent` is specified (that was the point of my config file: to create and recreate it automatically).

Comment: @A.B. for now, I think that there is a bug in `Storage=permanent` option of journald. It just behaves like `Storage=auto`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `/usr/lib/systemd/hello.conf.d/hello.conf` instead of `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` ??

You can **alternatively** use `/lib/systemd/journald.conf.d/*.conf` but not what you used.

Look at [journald.conf man page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html)

Note: Ubuntu 15.04 use /lib and not /usr/lib for *systemd*

Comment: No, you look at the man page (how could I invent this horror without looking at the man page?): `When packages need to customize the configuration, they can install configuration snippets in /usr/lib/systemd/*.conf.d/`. My package name is *hello*, so the file name is /usr/lib/systemd/hello.conf.d/hello.conf. I don't understand that liberal asterisk usage in the doc.

Comment: My remark that Ubuntu use /lib instead o f /usr/lib still stands and you did not state what you were trying to achive exactly.

Comment: That was clearly stated: to store logs permanently.

Comment: So I answered: use `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`

Comment: Ok, then it is wrong at least for two reasons: it isn't working (doesn't create a dir automatically), packages are not supposed to change the journald.conf.

Comment: You didn't talk about a package, first. that's my point

Comment: I don't like that kind of attitude.